# GRASS GIS - Plot Legend using Text Only Version

Tags: grass-gis, legend, text

If a person uses the text only version of grass on a remote system, how do you output the legend as a graphics file?

such as: r.out.tiff input=mymap output=file.tiff

but have it print the legend as well, or even just the legend itself.

d.legend does not work becuase there is no xwin etc..

Comment: Please replace your ALL CAPS title with mixed case by using the [edit] button beneath your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. [d.rast.legend](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/d.rast.leg.html) for this when using the [PNG driver](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/pngdriver.html) as display output. All display commands can write to the PNG driver, i.e. output into that file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you MarkusN :)

It took me awhile to figure out your solution, but for those that may have a similar issue, they may find what I used, with your advice, to be helpful :)

Within the Bash script that calls GRASS, I did the following:

```
# First call the PNG driver to use as "Monitor" since it is a 
# remote system without a display to use

export GRASS_PNGFILE=yourfile.png
export GRASS_RENDER_TRUECOLOR=TRUE # if needed, if not it will default to "False"
export GRASS_WIDTH= your value in pixels eg. 800
export GRASS_HEIGHT= your value in pixels eg. 600
d.mon start=PNG
# Below is what tells GRASS to plot the legend! :)
d.rast.leg rast=RasterName map=MapName num_of_lines=How many colors are your ramp
d.rast rastname (to plot the map with the legend)
# d.vect somevectormap (to use if your map is vector instead of raster)
d.mon stop=PNG  # Here we close the PNG driver

# After the file is plotted, make sure grass uses
"d.erase -f" # to clear your driver, if not run it yourself :)
```

Thanks again MarkusN for your guidance :)